# How can I change tabs when testing Nintex form with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, sharepoint-2013

I have a Nintex for where I have setup tabs as described in this post.
https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1198

Using a choice control displaying as buttons, and rules hiding panels.

I am creating a selenium test to test some of our common SharePoint forms and controls, but can't get selenium to trigger the rule to hide and unhide the panels when clicking the tab buttons.

Has anyone else tried testing Nintex forms with Selenium and solved this issue?

Just to clarify what software I am using. I have SharePoint 2013 on premise with Nintex Forms 2013 and I am creating a C# selenium WebDriver script.